# Chrome Extension to show a toggle to enable/disable extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest

```
{
    "name": "my-extension",
    "version": "0.0.9",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/icon16.png",
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "data/links.json"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [...],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
    ]
}
```

I'd like a toggle to be in `html/popup.html` so that when the user clicks it, I can store some boolean to know if my extension is enabled or disabled. Then in the `content_scripts` I can use this boolean to know whether to perform tasks or not.

So far I have a basic `html/popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body id="popup">
    <button>
        <!-- Somehow add a text on/off here based on the state -->
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to synchronise the information between your popup and your content script. For example:

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <button id="toggle"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

**popup.js**

```
var enabled = false; //disabled by default
var myButton = document.getElementById('toggle');

chrome.storage.local.get('enabled', data => {
    enabled = !!data.enabled;
    myButton.textContent = enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
});

myButton.onclick = () => {
    enabled = !enabled;
    myButton.textContent = enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
    chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:enabled});
};
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.get('enabled', data => {
    if (data.enabled) {
        //it is enabled, do accordingly
    } else {
        //it is disabled
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good straightforward and supported solution. As an aside, if anyone wants to explore something extra, try chrome.declarativeContent API with an allegedly experimental RequestContentScript action (it seems to have problems with pure CSS injection and incognito mode) to toggle the content script dynamically.